# How to match few words from a string to filter array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have two arrays. One has multiple fields and `Name` field, another one has only `Name` field. I want to filter array items from first array based on 2nd array `Name`. My first array

```
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GRP.Compiled.Release"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GPST.NonPermit.Inacitve"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
},
{
   "Failed": 0,
   "Resume": false,
   "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
},
```

I have one more array `Names` only with `Name` field

```
{
    "Name": "NonSubmit"
},
{
    "Name": "NonPermit"
},
```

This is my code which is not working

```
for (let i = 0; i < Names.length; i++)
{
   //let obj1=products.filter(x=>Names[i].search(/x.Name/g))
   var obj2=products.filter(x=>Names[i].includes(x.Name))
}
```

The first iteration I am looking for below output

```
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GPST.NonPermit.Inacitve"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
},
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.some`, you can check if `Name` value on `arr1` item contains the `arr2` item or not.

And based on that `some()` result, using `Array.prototype.filter`, you can filter the `arr1` items by `arr2` items.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GRP.Compiled.Release"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GPST.NonPermit.Inacitve"
},
{
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
},
{
   "Failed": 0,
   "Resume": false,
   "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
}];

const arr2 = [{
    "Name": "NonSubmit"
}, {
    "Name": "NonPermit"
}];

const output = arr1.filter(({ Name }) => arr2.some((item) => Name.includes(item.Name)));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer it works for me but I have little different requirement. I have 11 Name fields. In loop I can push all the items to preferred index and get count of every all items in every iteration in loop. Any how it that possible to do in loop. If yes you can update your answer with loop code.

Comment: 11 Name fields means each `arr2` item has 11 keys?

Comment: arr2 has 11 key but arr1 have nealy 1k items. As I am matching for part of string. So for every name I will get nearly 100 items

Comment: or can I do  `arr2[i].some` something like that inside loop.

Comment: so item on arr2 will be object and you can do like this. `arr1.filter((item1) => arr2.some((item2) => Object.entries(item2).every(([key, value]) => item1[key].includes(value))))`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "GRP.Compiled.Release"
  },
  {
      "Failed": 0,
      "Resume": false,
      "Name": "GPST.NonPermit.Inacitve"
  },
  {
      "Failed": 0,
      "Resume": false,
      "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
  },
  {
    "Failed": 0,
    "Resume": false,
    "Name": "PGVF.NonSubmit.Action"
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    "Name": "NonSubmit"
  },
  {
      "Name": "NonPermit"
  },
]

function solution() {
  return array1.filter((item1) => {
    let flag = false
    array2.forEach(item2 => {
      if (item1.Name.includes(item2.Name)) {
        flag = true
      }
    })
    return flag
  })
}

console.log(solution())
```